# Calculating Precision and Recall without binary data

Tags: statistics

I am currently working with recommender systems and would like to calculate the precision and recall of my models. The formulas for the precision and recall are as following:
$Precision= \frac{TP}{TP + FP}$, $Recall={\frac {TP}{TP+FN}}$

I was wondering how I should be able to calculate the true/false positives/negatives, since my calculation is a rating instead of binary data, e.g. predicted values are [4.7, 5.2, 3.4] and actual values are [5, 5, 3]. I have already calculated the MAE and RMSE of those values.

Comment: Why do you want to use this accuracy metric on non-binary data? It seems you are looking for an appropriate accuracy metric, so I would suggest looking into the MAPE or the RMSE, no?

Comment: @Steven31415 I would like to test beyond accuracy. I already have calculated the MAE and the RMSE, but would like to know how relevant the accuracy actually is, so i wanted to know the precision and recall to get an f-score.

Comment: the difficulty is that you need to determine what false positives and negatives are. Let's say you predict 5 and the actual value is 5; that could be a true positive. If you have predicted 4, that could be a true negative. But what is a false positive then? If you want to go beyond accuracy, I suggest taking a baseline model and check if your algorithm significantly works better than that model.